# ReactJS - render called, but DOM not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

This has happened to me a few times. I have always managed to work around the issue, yet I am still intrigued to understand why this happens, and what I have missed.

Essentially if I have a condition within my `render` method which specifies the class for my `div`:

```
let divClass = this.state.renderCondition ? 'red' : 'blue';
```

By default I set `renderCondition` within my state to false.

If I then define an `onClick` handler on a button (as follows), and click the button, whilst render **IS** called, the DOM is **NOT** updated. That is to say the class does not change.

```
onClickCompile: function() {

   this.setState({renderCondition: true}, function() {

        synchronousSlowFunction();
   });
}
```

This seems to have something to do with running slow synchronous code in that if the code is quick and simple the DOM **IS** updated appropriately.

If I wrap the call to `synchronousSlowFunction` in a 500 millisecond timeout, everything works as expected. I would however like to understand what I have misunderstood such that I do not need this hack.

Comment: can you see if anything happens in the `componentWillUpdate` hook, and compare it to your previous state? I am asking because something makes me feel like nothing actually changed.

Comment: I have verified - the lifecycle methods are all being called, and in the appropriate order (compnentWillUpdate, render, componentDidUpdate). The state is correct, just the DOM is not updated..

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava Please don't make minor edits that correct nonexistent "mistakes".

Comment: @IanKemp that minor 'mistakes' are grammar mistakes!!..which I suggest to the user when required..that's totally up to them whether they wanna fix their grammar or not..i am no one to force them!

Comment: The issue must be something unrelated to the code you've shown here, because doing the same things [in a CodePen](https://codepen.io/summitbc/pen/aPYQgp?editors=0110) works just fine for me.

Comment: can you please share a small demo using js fiddle/ code pen. as react doc. [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate]
 clearly as. setState callback is only called after component is updated, while `compenentdidupdate method` **is recommended instead** without leaving any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share the button onClick code? I might be wrong but this looks like an incorrectly set button onClick listener.

Make sure that onClick callback is defined without (), i.e.

```
<button onClick={this.something} />
```

instead of:

```
<button onClick={this.something()} />
```

Post more code so we can get a better (bigger) picture

Answer (score 0):

synchronousSlowFunction is as you mentioned synchronous. This means, that it blocks your component while it is running. That means, that react cannot update your component, because it has to wait for the callback function to complete until it can call render with the updated values. The setTimeout wrap makes the call asynchronous, so that react can render/update your component, while the function is doing its work. It is not the time delay, that makes it work but simply the callback, which is not render blocking. You could also wrap in in a Promise or make the slow function async to prevent render blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something Like this:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
   ...state, renderCondition: true
}));
```

Maybe you're doing another setState for renderCondition some where the code above should fix such things.

or maybe try using PureComponent

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

export default class TablePreferencesModal extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

After set state use this line

```
this.setState({})
```