# React doesn't update DOM during `render` when there is a long running function in `componentDidUpdate`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have the following situation in my board game interface based on React.

I have an event handler which updates state when players makes a move:

```js
const move = ...
this.setState(function (state, _props) {
   return this.apply_move(state, move);
});

apply_move(state, move) {
   let board_copy = _.cloneDeep(state.board);
   // applies the move to board_copy somehow
   ...
   return {
     board: board_copy,
   };
}
```

Then I want to first render my move and then run the AI to produce a move for the bot: this function call takes several seconds while AI is calculating its move. It's actually calling a WebAssembly function.

I put the request for AI move in `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.history.length > prevState.history.length) {
      if (this.botHasToMove()) {
        this.getMoveFromBot();   // <--- this runs for 5 seconds
      }
    }
}
```

I expect that this will run after the call to `render`, so I will first see my move rendered and then there will be a pause for a couple of seconds while AI is calculating and then AI move should be rendered.

However, the problem is that even though I see `render` called in the console before requesting AI's move and I can see that the state was updated with my move, but the DOM itself *is not updated*. It is only updated when the long call to get AI move is completed and one more `render` happens. Then both moves are rendered simultaneously and I can see them in the browser.

I would expect that each call to `render` should update the DOM (if there something had changed, and in my case it had), but for some reason the DOM update doesn't happen.

If I don't invoke the long call to AI in `componentDidUpdate` everything is working fine and I can see the effect of the first `render`.

Could somebody please explain why is this happening and teach me what is the proper way to force update of the DOM in the first `render` call?

Comment: Generally speaking, wanting, or needing, to force an update is a red flag your program flow is flawed. If I understand you correctly, you want to make a move and update state (and render), then allow the AI to make a move and update state (and render). Is this correct? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your component code?

Comment: One option to avoid blocking the main thread while calculating the AI move might be to use a WebWorker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731650/is-it-possible-to-run-webassembly-code-async?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, I think the problem here is that calling long running WebAssembly function is blocking the main thread and even though `render` was called and finished, the browser didn't have a change to actually update the DOM.

Comment: It looks like I was able to get my first move rendered by using `setTimeout(() => this.getMoveFromBot(), 10);` instead of just `this.getMoveFromBot()` in `componentDidUpdate` above. Apparently taking 10ms break (or even 1ms) gives it a chance to update the DOM.

Comment: It looks like this question is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490837/reactjs-render-called-but-dom-not-updated

Comment: Using the timeout (even with delay `0`) works because it moves the resultant state update into a callback placed at the end of the event queue so all the queued updates from the current render cycle can process and re-render. I am sure you can achieve the same in a more correct manner by using a "whose turn is it" state value and implement each "turn" via the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function.

Comment: @DrewReese but it looks I've already done what you suggesting, i.e. I have a function `this.botHasToMove()` which check what you call "whose turn is it" (it checks a boolean from `this.state`) and I put the request to the AI's move in `componentDidUpdate` (as you can see in the original question). Not quite sure how that is conceptually different to what you are suggesting...

Comment: @DrewReese Perhaps I don't understand, so what do you exactly mean by "implement each turn via the `componentDidUpdate` function"? Human and AI turns are quite different: human turns are produced in an event handler which just normally updates the state. And AI turns are produced by a long running WebAssembly call, which has to be called at some point immediately after getting and rendering human's move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the questions you have made, because I like this kind of problem, your actually doing great with your code, but there's a problem with your code, you actually mention a long call or long execution code, JS run in a single thread, that means that all the processes runs in just one channel (thread), so i would highly recommend you to watching these two videos, about Event Loops in JS, it's the reason for your problem:

[How works Event Loops JS - JSConf.Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=685s)

[How works Event Loops JS - JSConf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

the short answer for your problem it's that you are blocking the thread execution in JS, I mean all the JS execution is executing sequentially in a "execution queue", so the next execution code won't execute until the previous ones got finished.

So how you can fix this ? to avoid blocking your thread, you need to execute your code in another thread, but JS is just a one thread execution language, so you really need something called [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), they allow you to run code in another "thread", so your problem is that you are blocking you execution queue, because of a long execution function is taking too long to be resolved.

I hope this can help you a lot and help you to understand how JS Event loops / execution queue works.